# How to adjust the Summary Format to expose a float** as a float[][]?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I'm using XCode to debug some code.  Specifically, the code that I'm debugging exposes a `float[][]` as `float**`.  I am unable to change this syntax, but I'm not certain it would help anyway.

After including a relevant breakpoint, I want to view the contents of the array in the Variables view of the debugger?

When I double-click on the variable in the list of Autos, I see that I can add a Summary Format which seems deceivingly like it might help, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to use it!

In conclusion, how do I use the Variables View to see the contents of my array of arrays of this primitive type without resorting to typing commands directly to GDB (which, I believe, can also perform this function)?

Comment: Note that `float**` doesn't carry any size information, so don't expect you can show the whole array without explicitly specifying the dimensions somehow.